# Merge PrimeFaces components resources (CSS/JS files)

Tags: primefaces

I want to ask if PrimeFaces provides any method/way for us to merge all their resources (component css/js files) officially without overriding their renderers.

Modifying their component renderer is not really an efficient and robust way to do this in my opinion.

Comment: Their 'resources' are already compressed... Where did you get the impression they are not?

Comment: Sorry that I might have given the wrong intention.
I mean to merge all their component CSS files

Comment: Same comment, where did you get the impression they are not?

Comment: I used the inspector & I saw that each time a component is loaded then their CSS file will be loaded as a single css file (< 2KB) and there are more than 10 component CSS files were being loaded. So that where I got the impression

Comment: Does not happen here, nor in the showcase... Do you have a custom PF version?

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3 & it's now PrimeFaces 6.1.4 on the showcase, so I think that the reason. 
I didn't use a custom PF version FYI.

Comment: PF 5.3 compressed resources too... they do that since before 4.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151678/discussion-between-toan-lu-and-kukeltje).